# Laravel 5 Fundamentals: Flash Messaging Timer not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am working along with @Jeffrey_way's L5 Fundamentals: Flash Messaging, lesson 20 and I am stuck here when coding JQuery in JavaScript to make the MSG disappear after 3 Secs, below is the Script:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('div.alert').not('.alert-important').delay(3000).slideup(300);
</script>
```

and this is the error I get in Chrome's console view:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).not(...).delay(...).slideup is not a function
```

It's worth mentioning that I am stuck since 3 days and I have had enough googling :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is .slideUp(300). You have it as all lower case.
[slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/)

Comment: Does it need to be camel case ?

Comment: Lower camel case yes. Javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: no delay is correct. Do you have a simple jsfiddle you can post or post the html you are using.

Comment: It might be because jquery hasnt loaded yet. Wrap it up in a ready.   
`$( document).ready( function(){  
    $('div.alert').not('.alert-important').delay(3000).slideUp(300);  
}`

Comment: now I am getting this error in the console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: Sorry having trouble getting my edits in properly. Add ); to the end
$( document).ready( function(){ 
$('div.alert').not('.alert-important').delay(3000).slideUp(300); 
});

Comment: Just one thing I am wondering why video series maker didn't included this ? anyhow thanks again SpeedOfSpin :)